# NETLIFYy las rutas de acceso a mi seccion de BLOG

Tags: html

Tengo un error con mi código necesito saber como puedo solucionar este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto ocurre cuando intento ingresar a mi sección blog dejaré el link de mi despliegue:

https://fascinating-kheer-27f32f.netlify.app/

```html
<ul class="container-ul">
    <li><a href="#home"> INICIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about-us">NOSOTROS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sample">CATALOGO</a></li>
    <li><a href="./public/pages/blog">BLOG </a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACTO</a></li>
</ul>
```

Esta es la estructura de mis carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo ese problema igualmente cuando intento acceder al modo `serve dist` desde Visual Studio Code me muestra el error. Chat GPT dice que tiene algo que ver las rutas pero la he revisado un sin fin de veces

Comment: No estoy seguro pero mira en src si hay algún archivo para configurar las rutas. Algo como routes. Si existe eso tienes que configurar la ruta de `blog.html` y luego ya podras usar href de la siguiente manera: `<li><a href="/blog">BLOG </a></li>` suponiendo que le hayas puesto la ruta /blog a tu fichero blog.html